# Can I use my own website template on ExpressionEngine / ModX?

Tags: templates, web, expressionengine

I'm new to ExpressionEngine and ModX, well I've barely started reading up on it and I need some encouragement before I dig dipper into learning either of them.

I've know they're both CMS utilities which allow you to create websites and manage them as wordpress would but I'd like to know if instead of building it completely from the ground up, if one can simply use a template, like one of those free HTML templates or a premium template and use one of those two CMS utilities to manage/update the content of the site.

I've looked around for some tutorials but the ones I've found only teach how to create a site from the ground up and I don't mind reading and learning as long as someone can tell me if it's possible to do what I mentioned before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can with MODx. You can use any HTML, css, javascript you want, no restrictions.

I don't know about ExpressEngine.

Comment: Thanks. I've only been reading on ExpressionEngine and haven't given ModX a chance yet. I'll take a deeper look into MODx.

Comment: is it possible to use PHP with MODx? It seems it's possible with ExpressionEngine and one of the templates I want to work with, uses PHP/HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: Yes you can use PHP anywhere you want in your templates with MODx in the form of "snippets"

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use whatever HTML you like with ExpressionEngine, whether it's code you write yourself or whether it comes from a template.